# JupyterLab: How to customize bash terminal?

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

How can I change `font-family` and `font-size` in bash terminal in Jupyter-Lab?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a crucial feature for you, you could install a development version of JupyterLab, navigate to settings and there modify a JSON configuration file for the terminal. I hope that this version will be released soon. See:

[image]